# ZXING Scanner, how to go back to previous activity

Tags: android, zxing

On Zxing, I made the Scanner as a new Activity, and I have a button on my other activity that will start a new intent which is the Scanner Activity. How can I go back to my first activity if scan is successful?

Comment: Are you using startActivityForResult(Intent,REQUEST_CODE)? Check out this tutorial for more info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: no. im using it as a library

Answer (score 0):

It does so automatically already, and always has. You would have to double-check your setup and provide more info otherwise, since there is more to what you are doing than you are stating here.